# R package psych two means in one variable after combining

Tags: r, variables, psych

I'm currently analysing data for a student project. 
During the analysis, I combined two variables into one with cbind():

```
interpas$GA02_01 <- cbind(interpas$LP02_01, interpas$ST02_01)
```

The two variables LP02_01 and ST02_01 are measuring the same questions but for different media-formats. There's no overlapping between the two. The structure is like this:

```
LP02_01 ST02_01
1        NA
NA       2
NA       5
4        NA
```

So they just get combined. 
When I calculate the mean with the built-in mean() function from R, I get the mean of the new variable GA02_01.

But when I'um using the mean function of the package psych, or any other function for descriptive statistics (like describe) from this package, it's calculating the two variables LP02_01 and ST02_01 still seperately.
Like this:

```
> describe(interpas$GA02_01)
   vars   n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 151 3.62 1.89      4    3.59 1.48   1   7     6 0.00    -1.24 0.15
X2    2  63 2.70 1.92      2    2.45 1.48   1   7     6 0.85    -0.64 0.24
```

Does anyone know a solution to this? Unfortunately, I need the descriptive functions skew and kurtosi from the psych package for further analysis and a function to check for normal distribution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `unlist` your data frame. **However** make sure thatr you are choosing the desired columns in the correct (for your usecase) manner. For example, when you use `cbind`, you create matrix. You can just use indexing, i.e. `df[1:2]` (for first and second columns) or by name, i.e. `df[,c("LP02_01", "ST02_01")]`. That way you result with a data frame object. Then you can just `unlist` and `describe()`, i.e.

```
psych::describe(unlist(interpas[, c("LP02_01", "ST02_01")]))
#   vars n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
#X1    1 4    3 1.83      3       3 2.22   1   5     4    0    -2.24 0.91
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i continue working with this variable? In the next step, I need to do a confirmatory factor analysis. Do I have to unlist the variable every time I use it?

Because when I look at the variable I get GA01_01.LP01_01 and GA01_01.ST01_01.

Isn't there a way to just create a new variable with the values of LP01_01 and ST01_01?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

I would look into Coalesce

so you would probably want something like:

```
df%>%
mutate(new_var = coalesce(old_var1, old_var2)%>%
select(-c(old_var1,old_var2))
```

here is the documentation for the function in dplyr.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/coalesce